# Custom method update not work, server return 500 (Internal Server)

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, I've set a viewset with a custom method update:

```
def update(self, request, pk=None):

    if request.user.role == 'admin':

        category = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(category, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid:
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({
        'status': 'Unauthorized',
        'message': 'You do not have permission for to do this'
        }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

this not work and the server return an error 500 (Internal Server); I've the follow custom method that work but update not work:

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

queryset = Category.objects.all()
serializer_class = CategorySerializer
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

def list(self, request):
    queryset = self.queryset
    serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)

def create(self, request):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

    if request.user.role == 'admin':
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad Request',
            'message': 'We cannot create this category'
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({
        'status': 'Unauthorized',
        'message': 'You are not a administrator'
        }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):

    category = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(category)

    return Response(serializer.data)

def update(self, request, pk=None):

    if request.user.role == 'admin':

        category = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(category, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid:
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({
        'status': 'Unauthorized',
        'message': 'You do not have permission for to do this'
        }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    pass
```

As you see, the method list, the method create and the method retrieve work, but not update.

What is the problem?

Comment: You're not calling `serializer.is_valid()`. Since the method `serializer.is_valid` is a non-false object, your code tries to save the serializer even if it's not valid.

Comment: Ohhhh, Thank you, i've forgotten those parenthesis, Thank You Very Much...